# How do you find the number of users whose first/last visits are the same website

Tags: postgresql

Given a table of `timestamp,user_id,country,site_id`.
How do you find the number of users whose first/last visits are the same website?

```
/* unique users first site*/
SELECT ts,SWE.site_id, SWE.user_id
FROM SWE
WHERE SWE.ts = (
    SELECT MIN(t.timestamp)
    FROM SWE t
    WHERE
      t.user_id = SWE.user_id
  )

/* unique users last site*/
SELECT ts,SWE.site_id, SWE.user_id
FROM SWE
WHERE SWE.ts = (
    SELECT max(t.timestamp)
    FROM SWE t
    WHERE
      t.user_id = SWE.user_id
  )
```

I am not sure how to count when these are equal?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the `DISTINCT ON` operator to pick out the first/last visits for each user, then aggregate over these to check if they're different.  something like:

```
WITH first_visits AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id) * FROM user_visits
  ORDER BY user_id, timestamp
), last_visits AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id) * FROM user_visits
  ORDER BY user_id, timestamp DESC
)
SELECT user_id,
  array_to_string(array_agg(DISTINCT site_id), ', ') AS sites,
  MIN(timestamp) AS first_visit, MAX(timestamp) as last_visit
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM first_visits
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM last_visits) x
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT site_id) = 1;
```

Comment: Could you explain a little bit? I am not following...Does the first part with WITH making a table of first visits and last visits?

Comment: they're known as [Common Table Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) and you can think of them as creating a temporary/intermediate table just for this query